# Why is Inkscape so pixelated on Mac?

Tags: macos, display, display-settings, inkscape

Why is Inkscape so pixelated on Mac? I have:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

And here is how I see Inkscape:

[image]
[[Click for larger image.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqWcq.png)

What can I do about it? How can I make Inkscape less pixelated?

I am using macOS High Sierra.

Comment: The issue seems to be that XQuartz doesn’t support retina displays: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1216795

Comment: @JamesP, I installed it using Homebrew, but now I do not know how to change the theme to a black one, since there is no folder themes. ) :

Comment: It might help if you specified your macOS version.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  (Use the appropriate [macos-xxxx] tag.)